# iPad Air 2 on iOS 11 after enrolling with Apple MDM profile manager through Apple Configurator 2 is stuck on Remote management screen

Tags: ipad, osx-server, ios, mobile-device-management, profile-manager

I install OS X Server for MDM profile manager on iMac with High Sierra.   Then used Apple Configurator 2.5 to enroll 16 iPad Air 2 on iOS11 to the MDM and added wifi Profile.   All iPads are showing up as supervised devices on AC2.  Now on each iPad, I see the Remote Management screen,  hit the NEXT on the top right corner to attempt to install the remote management,  and they all came back saying failed timed out.
The same profile worked fine on iMac.

Comment: Can you confirm the wifi is working on one of the iPads, even though you loaded a wifi Profile?

Comment: Already confirmed wifi works.  I tried to use Safari on the ipad to access my MDM profile manager and click enroll there,  it downloaded the same profile,  and again failed on the install with timeout.  I did the same with a Mac and I was able to install the profile.   So it is a problem with iOS 11.  I tested with multiple iPads and they all failed with timeout.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the reason, look at [Apple's compatibility list of devices](https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-2/requirements-cadbf9a73b/mac) for Apple Configurator 2 -- iPad Air 2 is not listed.